# How to get signed_request during authentication in facebook for iOS?

Tags: ios, facebook, api

I am implementing travel applicaiton with facebook login. I want to get signed_req string after the facebook login using iphone facebook sdk. But i am getting only access token in response.

Can you please help me on this query.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: AFAIK a signed_request is only issued if you access a Canvas App. Not natively in iOS.

Comment: @Tobi is right. Can you give details of the call you make and the response you receive?